# Insert keyframe into m4v/mp4 at specific times

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I have a program for educators (written with `electronjs` framework) that plays videos, skipping to preset points in the video as defined in a companion JSON file. Sometimes there is a significant lag after a skip, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110932/2903532) suggests that the lag is there because of infrequent keyframes.

Assuming this is correct, I would like to insert keyframes at exact points in the mp4 file where I know the player will skip to. However, some of these video files are already quite large, so I do not want to decrease the keyframe interval, thereby making the files even larger. I only need to force a handful of keyframes in the entire file.

I would like to be able to pass an argument (to `ffmpeg`, for example) with the times at which I want to force keyframes. Preferably, I would like to do this without re-encoding the entire video (just like [this unanswered question](https://superuser.com/q/1313522/403078)), but if I have to reencode the video, I could do that too.

Comment: have you had a look at the -force_key_frames option? eg `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -force_key_frames 0:05:00,0:10:00 out.mp4` ... that will put a keyframe as close to the 5 and 10s mark as it can

Comment: In theory, this can be done without re-encoding the entire video - basic idea is to segment the source stream to one GOP per segment. Re-encode the offending segments to the same bitstream parameters as the source and then restitch using the concat demuxer.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Both your example and the docs use times in the `HH:MM:SS` format. Can the times be expressed as just seconds? (e.g. `7200.132` instead of `2:00:00.132`)

Comment: looks like it does revert to seconds if you just supply a single number (no colons). quick way to check if there are frames inserted where you want them is `/ffprobe -select_streams v:0  -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time out.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg to insert keyframes where you want them using the `-force_key_frames` option.

eg:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -vcodec libx264 -force_key_frames 0:05:00,0:10:00 out.mp4
```

will put a keyframe as close to the 5 and 10s mark as it can. The time values can be in hh:mm:ss format, or just seconds (single values, no colons).

You can check if there are frames inserted where you want them using:

```
./ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and the output quality is lower. Is there a simple way to match input framerate, etc. or do I need to specify all of that manually?

Comment: I haven't actually checked the quality manually. I just assume it's lower quality because the file is much smaller.

Comment: you might want to try adding `-c:a copy -c:v copy` to explicitly copy audio and video before the `-force...` (see edited answer)

Comment: Without reencoding the `-force_key_frames` option will have no effect, so the above command to add keyframes does nothing at all (since the `-c:v copy` keep the same videostream without reencoding).

Comment: this is just totaly incorrect