# Video is lagging when using currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a simple HTML page and I play a video on the page. I use the scrollbar as the seekbar. In other words, video plays as long as the user scrolls.

I've seen this effect used in couple places and wanted to create it myself. The script I wrote is fully functioning, but there's a small problem: the video itself.

The videos from the examples run smoothly, but the videos that I created, they lag. I can't seem to figure out the cause. I've tried different combination of FPS, resolution, bit rate, but they didn't help.

The only difference among the videos that I could find is when I play the videos from the examples, I can seek any frame on MPC (K-Lite). I can seek only 3-4 frames on the videos that I've created. So the problem might be related to that. I'm not sure. If it's about that, I need a way to make the videos fully seekable. How do I do that?

https://akinuri.github.io/sticky-scrollable-video/ (online demo)

https://github.com/akinuri/sticky-scrollable-video (repo, check for details)

https://www.audi.com.tr/tr/web/tr/modeller/a8/a8-l.html (sticky scrollable video)

codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc (scrollable video)

Online demo plays the smooth/seekable video (from Audi). To see the difference between videos, you have to download the project from GitHub. Two videos (Audi and Chrome_ImF.ogv) are smooth/seekable. Other two (Chrome_icon, bedroom.mp4) are problematic/lags (only few frames are seekable).

---

<sub>Chrome/Opera produces smoother playback than Firefox. I'm using Premiere Pro for the videos.</sub>

<sub>**Edit:** While the linked question talks about the same problem, I can't mark my question as a duplicate of it. Why? It's 3 years old, has only 1 answer, the answer isn't accepted, and it is poor. Video editing isn't my main occupation, so I can't make a direct inference from an answer. Answers should be given elaborately. My Q/A is more detailed. So I doubt that anyone viewing both questions would prefer the old one to this.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting currentTime for HTML5 video window.onscroll is lagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741233/setting-currenttime-for-html5-video-window-onscroll-is-lagging)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is indeed about seekability. I've found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35741233/2202732) related to this problem and it made me look into key frames a little deeper.

I was looking for a way to modify the key frames (in Premiere Pro) and I found it in

```
Export Settings (CTRL+M) -> Video -> Advanced Settings -> Key Frame Distance
```

> The keyframe distance is the maximum number of frames before the encoder inserts an i-frame,...

<sup>https://forums.adobe.com/message/9451877#9451877</sup>

This setting was not ticked, and was set to `72`. So depending on the FPS, it equals to 1-2 seconds. To make all the frames seekable, I've set this to `1` and it worked.

**Update:** It turns out that playing videos with low KFD on mobile (Chrome, Samsung Internet) is problematic. While `StickyScrollableVideo` can play the video (using `currentTime`), it is laggy. On the other hand, `video.play()` fails. Video just doesn't play. So instead of using `StickyScrollableVideo` on mobile, I'll disable it and just play the video. And to be able to do that, I need a version of the video with a higher KFD. So I prepared two videos; one with KFD:1 for desktop/`StickyScrollableVideo`, and other with KFD:25 (FPS) for mobile/`video.play()`.

Issue can be seen here: https://akinuri.github.io/in-view-tracker/video.html

First video is with KFD:1, and the second is KFD:25. Tap on videos to play/pause.

Comment: Then the right thing to do is either mark this as duplicate, or delete the question because clearly "searching for the answer first" by future visitors will lead them to find that answer, too?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans True, but I'm not really that content with that Q/A. There's only one answer and the OP didn't accept it. Even though I suspected the problem to be about key frames, I didn't know where to look, and what to look for (Not a video guy). And that answer alone doesn't help much. So, I'll keep my Q/A since it's more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You must know root of this bug is CPU usage for complete page work (your video staff + all other job). In your example look like video encoder (mp4) bug. To make full response for all browsers you need both (safari,firefox,chrome) video format.

- One way is theory: Use web workers (new thread) to play video and navigate from code.
- Second is drawing video blob direct in canvas2d. In canvas program you can easy void to the current frame.

  Did you try on other (better) computer with similar environment and same browser version?

This will fix you problem 50%. Just  conver mp4 to the ogg ( .ogv ) format

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: The specs of the computer I tested the code on are i7-8700k 3.7Ghz, 16 GB RAM, and GTX 1060 6GB. So I don't think it's a hardware (or video format) related problem. And like you said, I've tested this on multiple machines. My machine just played less laggy than the others. The problem was about key frames. But I didn't try different options to play the videos (web workers, canvas, etc.), because the videos from the examples played just fine. Changing the key frame distance solved the problem.