# What is the most lag-free way of moving back X frames in a video/animation on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html5-video

I'm putting my thesis presentation online, as a video with custom controls for going forward (similar to a powerpoint) between "slides" of an animated video. Some transitions between two "slides" need to repeat in a ~1 second loop, and the repeating part is where the lag happens.

This is the only solution I've tried, since I don't have the time (the presentation is on Friday) nor the expertise needed to know what other video/animated image formats work well. I'm going to play around with different file formats (ogg, webm) to see if that makes a difference.

[Live website with thesis presentation.](http://524.se)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video
        id="video-active"
        width="640"
        height="390"
        controls="">
        <source src="presentation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    video = document.querySelector("#video-active");
    framerate = 60;
    thresholdFrameNo = 300;
    timeToRevert = 0.5;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.querySelector("#video-active").defaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
    $("#video-active").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
      onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
    })});

    function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
        currentFrame = Math.round(currentTime*framerate);
        if(currentFrame > thresholdFrameNo){
            video.currentTime -= timeToRevert;
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I expect the video to go to the position half a second earlier really fast, but it freezes for a bit (maybe up to half a second) at the old seek position, before playing.

Comment: So you want to be able to play the video in chapters throughout the duration?

Comment: Just edit your video so it does what you want in its original form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741233/setting-currenttime-for-html5-video-window-onscroll-is-lagging) whose top answer pointed me towards the keyframe issue, enabling me to fix the issue by using the output of the following FFmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=5 out.mp4`

where `keyint=5` indicates a keyframe every five frames (pointed out in [this](https://serato.com/forum/discussion/114735) forum thread).